# not able to set extra space

Tags: android, android-layout

I am not able to set extra space at the bottom of two buttons in my activity_main.xml
Here's my activity_main.xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/main_bg_edited"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    style="@style/top_bar_style">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewMain"
        style="@style/page_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewMainDelete"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/delete" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:background="@drawable/box_midbg" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/main_editText_category_name"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/main_editText_category_name"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/main_editText_category_name"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="Name:"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/main_editText_unit"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/main_editText_category_name"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main_editText_category_name"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/main_editText_unit"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/main_editText_unit"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:text="Unit:" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/main_editText_attribute"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/main_editText_unit"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main_editText_unit"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/main_editText_attribute"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/main_editText_attribute"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="Attribute:" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/main_editText_limit"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/main_editText_attribute"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main_editText_attribute"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/main_editText_limit"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/main_editText_limit"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:text="Limit:" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/main_button_save"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/main_editText_limit"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main_editText_limit"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/save_btn"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:text="Save" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/main_button_cancel"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/main_button_save"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/main_button_save"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/main_editText_limit"
        android:background="@drawable/save_btn"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:typeface="sans" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the button tag, even if i use **android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"** or **android:layout_paddingBottom="100dp"**, in either case, there's no change in my layout. Buttons are still at the bottom of the inner relative-layout.

Please help me out of this. And please explain me (in detail, if possible) why this happens. This the third time i'm stuck with spacing matter. Before, i used to get out using **layout_margin** or **layout_padding** (doing trial and error method). But now, even this is not working. Help me with explanation, on what to do when such a situation arise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `android:layout_padding` use `android:paddingBottom="100dp"` to see if that makes a difference.

Here's a link to the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:paddingBottom

Comment: yeah bro, i even tried this, thought it might work but it didn't.

Comment: bro you were not wrong, it was just, i think, you forgot to tell that use **android:paddingBottom="100dp"** in the inner relativeLayout tag. Anyway, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the attribute

```
android:paddingBottom="100dp"
```

to your RelativeLayout (`relativeLayout2`).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Would you please explain me when to use padding and when to use margin. I'm little confused. If you could provide me with any kind of tutorial, would be grateful to you.

Comment: @shree202, `padding` will set the amount of space between the edge of a View and its children. So for a `ViewGroup` (such as a `RelativeLayout`), this is the distance between the border and anything within the layout. `Margin` refers to the space outside of a view - such as the distance between two views at the same layout level (such as the two buttons in your layout).

Comment: Thank you so much, bro. How could you explain so nicely...!!! You won't believe, but i had gone through the site developer.android.com, still i was not able to make out the difference between them and how to use them (May be i'm not that smart right now). But now, i am ready to work with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

PAdding provides internal spacing to the button or anything while margin provides outer spacing.
So, add android :layout_marginBottom to your Relativelayout2

Comment: Thanks a lot, sis. Your answer is appreciable too. You are putting good efforts. Nice. Keep it up.